# Which regression analysis to use?

Tags: regression, logistic

[image: Sample of dataset]
I have percentage change data compared to a baseline of public and private transport activity over 1 year. With the help of one or two independent variables I want to analyze if there is a switch between each mode or what is the probability that a certain mode is preferred. Which is the best analytical method to do this? and how do i go about it?
Do i consider public and private transport percentage changes as two different dependable variables and or is there a way where i can use both in the same analysis?

EDIT: I have added a sample of my dataset as an edit. I believe i will to do separate regressions on the different transport modes but i am not sure how to handle the nature of my dependent variables.

Comment: I am having a hard time following what your setup is (though it sounds like logistic regression is a good starting point). It would help if you could arrange some sample data in a data frame: one variable per column, one observation (across all variables) per row, kind of like headers in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for your reply. I have percentage change of a mode of transport compared to a baseline (dont know the absolute value of the baseline) and the percentage change increase and decrease (+ and - ive values). Then i have an independent variable that influences the change. How do i use a logistic regression for this? I believe i need binary values or values ranging from 0 to1. Is there any way i can transform the data i have to data i can use to do a regression? I will attach a same of my dataset.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).

Comment: I did type my question as a text, i just uploaded a sample of my dataset as a picture cause i couldnt find out how to upload an excel file.